# Shorter way to use OLS with statsmodels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, regression

I am currently using the code below to regress over a list `x`. Unfortunately, for more than a linear model the code gets quite long. Is there a shorter way to use OLS with statsmodels? Maybe a function that lets me choose to which degree I want to create the regression?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Parameters
param0 = np.ones(len(x))
param1 = x
param2 = np.square(x)
params = np.array( list(zip(param0,param1,param2)) )
# OLS
mod = sm.OLS(y, params).fit()
```